# Equation involving hyperbolic tangents

Tags: trigonometry, closed-form, hyperbolic-functions

I started with a rather complicated equation, and eventually managed to write it in the form
$$
\left\{
\tanh \left(\frac{a\left(x-b\right)}{2}\right)
-
\tanh \left(\frac{ax}{2}\right)
+
2 \log
\left[
\frac{1+\tanh \left(\frac{a\left(x-b\right)}{2}\right)}
{1+\tanh \left(\frac{ax}{2}\right)}
\right]
\right\}
\times c
+
a\left(x-b\right)
=
d,
$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are constant parameters, and I would like to solve the equation for $x$. I tried the well-known trigonometric identities for the $\tanh\left(\cdot\right)$, but did not get any closer to obtain a closed-form solution for $x$. Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed, or whether there exists a closed-form solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: With $x$ inside and outside $\tanh$, this is a [transcendental equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) with no closed-form solution.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way to rigorously show that this particular transcendental equation does not have a closed-form solution? Wikipedia indeed says that most transcendental equations where the variable appears both as an argument of the transcendental function and somewhere else cannot be solved in closed form, I'm just wondering if this can somehow be shown for this particular equation.